# Return NULL data types in C++ native client from SQL Server

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, type-conversion, sql-server-native-client

I'm writing small C++ console application (VS 2013 / Windows7) that uses SQL Server native client sqlncli.h. I'm have trouble with NULL fields in program - I'm not see right values in out.

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h> 
#include <sqlncli.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SQLHENV environHandle;
    SQLHDBC connectHandle;
    SQLHSTMT statement; 
    SQLWCHAR* connectString = (SQLWCHAR*)TEXT("Driver={SQL Server};Server=XX.XX.XX.XX;Database=DBNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
    SQLRETURN status;
    status = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &environHandle);
    cout << "SQLAllocHandle returned " << status << "\r\n";
    if (status == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO || status == SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        status = SQLSetEnvAttr(environHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3_80, SQL_IS_INTEGER);
        cout << "SQLSetEnvAttr returned " << status << "\r\n";
        if (status == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO || status == SQL_SUCCESS)
        {
            status = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, environHandle, &connectHandle);
            cout << "SQLAllocHandle SQL_HANDLE_DBC returned " << status << "\r\n";
            if (status == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO || status == SQL_SUCCESS)
            {
                status = SQLDriverConnect(connectHandle, NULL, connectString, SQL_NTS, NULL, 256, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
                cout << "SQLDriverConnect returned " << status << "\r\n";
                if (status == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO || status == SQL_SUCCESS)
                {
                    status = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, connectHandle, &statement);
                    cout << "SQLAllocHandle SQL_HANDLE_STMT returned " << status << "\r\n";
                    if (status == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO || status == SQL_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        status = SQLExecDirect(statement, (SQLWCHAR*)TEXT("SELECT * FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[Table1]"), SQL_NTS);
                        cout << "SQLExecDirect returned " << status << "\r\n";
                        if (status == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO || status == SQL_SUCCESS)
                        {
                            int rec_id;
                            int id;
                            char date[64];
                            char ps[201];
                            while (SQLFetch(statement) == SQL_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                SQLGetData(statement, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &rec_id, 0, NULL);
                                SQLGetData(statement, 2, SQL_C_ULONG, &id, 0, NULL);
                                SQLGetData(statement, 3, SQL_C_CHAR, date, 64, NULL);
                                SQLGetData(statement, 4, SQL_C_CHAR, ps, 201, NULL);
                                cout << rec_id << " " << id << " " << date << " " << ps << endl;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    cout << "Connected;"; 
                    cin.get();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Table1 structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [rec_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ps] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In console out I see first 3 fields correct, but fourth field is like  ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ How to catch NULL fields of type VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, FLOAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument for the `SQLGetData` function is

> StrLen_or_IndPtr
>
> [Output] Pointer to the buffer in which to return
>   the length or indicator value. If this is a null pointer, no length or
>   indicator value is returned. This returns an error when the data being
>   fetched is NULL.  SQLGetData can return the following values in the
>   length/indicator buffer:
>
> The length of the data available to return
>   SQL_NO_TOTAL
>   SQL_NULL_DATA

You are currently passing `NULL` for this, but if you provide a pointer to a valid `SQLLEN` variable then you can check for the `SQL_NULL_DATA` return.

Also, if you initialise your buffer (e.g. `char ps[201] = {0};`) then you won't get the garbage print-out if no data is returned for a field.